# Mix Razor and Javascript code

Tags: c#, javascript, razor

I'm pretty confused with how to mix razor and js. This is the current function I am stuck with:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var data = [];

        @foreach (var r in Model.rows)
        {
                data.push([ @r.UnixTime * 1000, @r.Value ]);
        }
```

If I could declare c# code with `<c#></c#>` and everything else was JS code -- this would be what I am after:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var data = [];

        <c#>@foreach (var r in Model.rows) {</c#>
                data.push([ <c#>@r.UnixTime</c#> * 1000, <c#>@r.Value</c#> ]);
        <c#>}</c#>
```

What is the best method to achieve this?

Comment: Apparently the syntax highlighting is nice and confused with my `<c#>` tags as well :-P

Comment: Did you check the HTML output of this view? How does it look, and how you you want it to differ?

Comment: Throws up an error about `Conditional Compilation ` so I can't see the HTML -- so I believe it feels part of this is C# code.

Comment: It seems like a JavaScript error: http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=99780  . What is the exact error message, and where do you get it?

Comment: I think this is a case where trying to mix JS and C# so closely would be a pain to read/maintain. I'm glad the compiler disallowed you from this code. :)

Comment: @Kyle Brandt: you only need one `<text>` element that wraps around the contents of `@foreach`.

Comment: Dont do this at all. Export data to JS variable array or what and then use clean javascript.

Answer (score 376, accepted):

Use `<text>`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   var data = [];

   @foreach (var r in Model.rows)
   {
      <text>
            data.push([ @r.UnixTime * 1000, @r.Value ]);
      </text>
   }
</script>
```

Comment: Razor works fine in Javascript blocks when executed but I hate how the syntax highlighting gets all sorts of confused. It highlights all the Razor code as invalid Syntax because it's stuck in Javascript mode I believe.

Comment: what about if this code is in a bundle?? can I write code inside of a javascript file??

Comment: Works perfectly until you want to check if one variable is less than another and razor goes psycho!

Comment: @ncubica if you want razor in bundle, than somethings wrong in your concept. Razor is for views, not javascript.

Comment: @ncubica This post is old, but the solution to your question is: Write a function in a JS file, render it with `Scripts.Render`, then call the function in a `<script>` tag. Not exactly graceful, but it works for most (read: simple) use cases.

Comment: @Sinjai wao. time flies, these day webpack and react all way :P, I don't even remember the reason of my question.

Answer (score 96):

Inside a code block (eg, `@foreach`), you need to mark the markup (or, in this case, Javascript) [with `@:` or the `<text>` tag](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/15/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax.aspx).

Inside the markup contexts, you need to surround code with code blocks (`@{ ... }` or `@if`, ...)

Comment: Why do you say "mark the markup", this wouldn't be an issue if the content was, in fact, markup.

Comment: @Max: Even though it doesn't look like markup, it is markup.   (As opposed to server-side code)

Answer (score 63):

you also can simply use

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   var data = [];

   @foreach (var r in Model.rows)
   {
       @:data.push([ @r.UnixTime * 1000, @r.Value ]);
   }
</script>
```

note **@:**

Answer (score 13):

Never ever mix more languages.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var data = @Json.Encode(Model); // !!!! export data !!!!

    for(var prop in data){
      console.log( prop + " "+ data[prop]);
    }
```

In case of problem you can also try

```
@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
```

Comment: This is great, but also, there are legitimate instances where we need to mix. But this is the solution I used since it fit perfectly.

Comment: Note that this _is_ mixing languages. You have a statement that is half-JavaScript ("var data = ") and half-Razor/C# ("@Json.Encode(Model)"). It's just a less invasive mixing, but it is no less mixing than having a Razor/C# "foreach" whose body emits generated JavaScript. :-)

Comment: It returns `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &` because the model becomes something like this `[{&quot;Id&quot;:1,&quot;Name&quot;:&quot;Name}]`

Comment: This is the best and simplest solution.  Definitely need to feed the encoded JSON through Html.Raw() to get rid of the `&quot;` entities.

Answer (score 2):

A non conventional method to separate javascript from the view, but still use razor in it is to make a `Scripts.cshtml` file and place your mixed javascript/razor there.

Index.cshtml

```
<div id="Result">
</div>

<button id="btnLoad">Click me</button>

@section scripts
{
    @Html.Partial("Scripts")
}
```

Scripts.cshtml

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var url = "@Url.Action("Index", "Home")";

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#btnLoad").click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url ,
                data: {someParameter: "some value"},
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",

                success: function(msg) {
                    $("#Result").text(msg.d);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: if i need this aproach :  var action = "Index";
    var url = "@Url.Action(action, "Home")";

Answer (score 2):

This is my way to hack Razor and use Javascript without freaking out Intellisense.

Obviously you should use `<text>` but with an "expedient": double braces before.

This is what happens if a single brace is used:

[image]

This is what happen if a couple of braces are used:

[image]

Now constants and variable have been recognized.
It's better, but not good!
There is still the "less than" symbol that confuses intellisense making it think that following is the name of a tag. The "less than" sign is signaled as error and from here there are parsing errors as "console.log" shows.
You need to add something that quiets intellisense and doesn't get returned in the final JS code at compile time.

Solution: use this comment after "less than": `/*>*/`

This is the result

[image]

It's quite strange to see, but it works as it should.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `<text>` tag for both cshtml code with javascript

Comment: "<text>" tag is missing the above answer

Comment: use backticks or ctrl + k after selecting code to format it

Answer (score -3):

Wrap your Razor code in @{ } when inside JS script  and be aware of using just @
Sometimes it doesn't work:

```
function hideSurveyReminder() {
       @Session["_isSurveyPassed"] = true;
    }
```

This will produce

```
function hideSurveyReminder() {
       False = true;
    }
```

in browser =(