# Get rid of "Invalid character" warning in ASP.NET MVC 3 Razor syntax views?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mix Razor and Javascript code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5614941/mix-razor-and-javascript-code)

The following code produces an "Invalid character" warning in visual studio.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var model = {
        id: @(Model.Id),
        initalData: @(Html.Raw(ViewBag.InitalData))
    };
</script>
```

Is there any way to get rid of the warning?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think so.

Comment: BTW, you don't need the parentheses.

Comment: "Invalid character" has to be the most useless error ever thrown... how I hate it! I bet you the call to `@(Html.Raw(ViewBag.InitalData))` has some non-fatal parse error associated. I'd try hitting the same page using your Opera browser, which has better debugging capabilities.

Comment: @SLaks but w/o the parens I get even more warnings, "Conditional compilation" and "Expexcted expression"

Comment: @smcphill - this is a development time error, no browser

Comment: @Scott: True; I hadn't thought of that.