# How to switch from Razor to plain old HTML?

Tags: c#, javascript, razor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mix Razor and Javascript code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5614941/mix-razor-and-javascript-code)

Here is the code I'm trying to run:

```
    // Razor code!
    @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {

        // This is Javascript, NOT C#/Razor code. Hence the '@' symbol.
        var currentUser = @User.Identity.Name;

    } else {

        // Also Javascript code!
        var currentUser = null;
    }
```

Basically, I want to output this as Javascript if the user is logged in:

```
var currentUser = @User.Identity.Name;
```

Or this if the user is logged out:

```
var currentUser = null;
```

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5614941/mix-razor-and-javascript-code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well first you will want to change it to something like (remember your quotes around the `@User.Identity.Name`):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var currentUser = null;
@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {
    <text>
        currentUser = '@User.Identity.Name';
    </text>
}
</script>
```

Then add some javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (currentUser != null) {
    document.getElementById('loggedInUser').innerHTML = 'Welcome '+ currentUser;
}
</script>
```

Comment: It may need <text></text> around it...

Answer (score 2):

As soon as you start tag in Razor, it switches to markup (including `<script>`). If you don't need any tag, use `<text>` instead.

If you need quick copy/paste solution, take Tim's or Adam's as both do the job. However, as Razor uses pretty complex algorithms while parsing mix of several languages, it is worth providing [Phil Haack](http://haacked.com)'s [Razor part of quick reference](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx) in its entirety (allowed by CC-BY license):

> Code Block:
>
> ```
> @{ 
>   int x = 123; 
>   string y = "because.";
> }
> ```
>
> Expression (Html Encoded):
>
> ```
> <span>@model.Message</span>
> ```
>
> Expression (Unencoded):
>
> ```
> <span>
> @Html.Raw(model.Message)
> </span>
> ```
>
> Combining Text and markup:
>
> ```
> @foreach(var item in items) {
>   <span>@item.Prop</span> 
> }
> ```
>
> Mixing code and Plain text:
>
> ```
> @if (foo) {
>   <text>Plain Text</text> 
> }
> ```
>
> Mixing code and plain text (alternate):
>
> ```
> @if (foo) {
>   @:Plain Text is @bar
> }
> ```
>
> Email Addresses:
>
> ```
> Hi philha@example.com
> ```
>
> Explicit Expression:
>
> ```
> <span>ISBN@(isbnNumber)</span>
> ```
>
> Escaping the @ sign:
>
> ```
> <span>In Razor, you use the 
> @@foo to display the value 
> of foo</span>
> ```
>
> Server side Comment:
>
> ```
> @*
> This is a server side 
> multiline comment 
> *@
> ```
>
> Calling generic method:
>
> ```
> @(MyClass.MyMethod<AType>())
> ```
>
> Mixing expressions and text:
>
> ```
> Hello @title. @name.
> ```

I left out Razor delegate since there are [Razor helpers](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/05/12/asp-net-mvc-3-and-the-helper-syntax-within-razor.aspx) now.

Comment: In which way does this answer the OP?

Comment: OP asked for switching between contexts. I think my answer is suitable.

Comment: In that page, there is a no reference to switching contexts. You should make it clear that what the OP needs is switching contexts, and what exactly the OP needs.

Comment: I don't doubt that. I am just saying that, for who asked the question, or who has the same doubt as the OP, a link like that probably doesn't help much. If the answer would say "see examples 4-6 on this page" that would be more helpful. I would also quote the example, just in the case the page is not accessible to future readers.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>

    @if( User.Identity.IsAuthenticated ) {
        <text>var currentUser = "@User.Identity.Name";</text>
    }
    else {
         <text>var currentUser = null;</text>
    }

    alert(currentUser);

</script>
```

Which produces an output of:

```
var currentUser = "Foo Bar";
alert(currentUser);
```

@Adam Plocher's answer shows a cleaner way to represent it (removing the JavaScript variable declaration from the server script).

An even cleaner way to represent it in a single, slightly easier-to-understand line:

```
<script>
    var currentUser = '@(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated ? User.Identity.Name : "Anonymous" )';
    alert(currentUser);
</script>
```

Comment: All the answers has been down-voted. I wonder what is wrong with this one.

Comment: My first version could have been better. I believe both of the current samples answer the question and they have both been tested.