# Keep showing visible div when doing postback

Tags: c#, jquery, html, razor, ispostback

I got some JQuery code that hides elements on my page. However I would like to keep showing the visible element when a `page_load` event has appeared.

Im using cshtml(razor) code, and in there I have a `IsPost` call, and I was wondering if a call to the JQuery `.hide` was possible.

The JQuery code:

```
<script>
    $().ready(function () {
        $(".btn").click(function () {
            $(".Hide").hide("fast");
            $("#" + $(this).data('type')).show("fast");
        });
    });
</script>
```

The C# code:

```
if(IsPost)
{
    if(Request["btn"] == "btn1")
    {
         // Do some code
    }


    if(Request["btn"] == "btn2")
    {
         // Do some other code
    }
}
```

The html code:

```
<div id="button1" class="Hide">
    <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="submit" name="btn" value="btn1" />
    </form>
</div>
<div id="button2" class="Hide">
    <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="submit" name="btn" value="btn2" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: if you are using razor you can combine what razor and javascript and control what part of js you want to execute with razor

Comment: @COLDTOLD could you give an example?

Comment: ke a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5614941/mix-razor-and-javascript-code

Answer (score 0):

The answer I finally used looks like this:

```
<script>
$().ready(function () {
    $(".btn").click(function () {
        $(".Hide").hide("fast");
        $("#" + $(this).data('type')).show("fast");
    });

    @{
        if(IsPost)
        {
            <text>
                $("#btn1).show("fast");
            </text>
        }
    }
});
</script>
```