# using Razor C# with javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to use razor c# in my javascript. However it's telling me: The name 'isReport' does not exist in the current context

My code is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var isReport = false;
    @if(Model.columns != null)
    {
        isReport = true;
    }
    alert(isReport);
    if(isReport)
        $("#reports").dataTable();
</script>
```

I'm trying to do the same this as in this post I think...
[Mix Razor and Javascript code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5614941/mix-razor-and-javascript-code)

Thanks!

Comment: Yes; and the answer to that question is also the answer to this one.

Comment: But you aren't following the advice of the answers in that post.  Use `<text>` or `@:` to identify the `isReport = true` line as JavaScript and not Razor code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `@:` on your `isReport` assignment (inside the `if`):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var isReport = false;
    @if(Model.columns != null)
    {
        @:isReport = true; //change is here
    }
    alert(isReport);
    if(isReport)
        $("#reports").dataTable();
</script>
```