# combine C# and javascript code

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

i have a `javascript` alert in C# code like this

```
if(Session["msg"] != null){
       string msg = (string)Session["msg"];
       if(msg.Length > 2) {
           @: var msg = @msg;
           @: alert(msg);
                               }
```

But in the view the alert doesn't appear:

[image: result]

The problem is that the alert message is written to the view.

Why does this happen? How can I fix this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5614941/mix-razor-and-javascript-code

Comment: It's doing some form of escaping. A lot of template languages do this by default. I don't know anying about C# or the razor framework, but it may be worth looking into the razor documentation... there are a ton of answers on here that solve this problem `@Html.Raw()` or something like that.

Comment: If this code block is placed inside <script> tags, it should work. Also you are missing quotes on msg

Comment: @user619656 can you explain more plz

Comment: You can see the message in the view because is rendered as text inside/as html. What you want rendered by MVC is: <script> var msg="alert message"; alert(msg);</script>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap the injected Razor string in quotes:

```
@: var msg = "@msg";
```

Let's say the content of "msg" is "Something" ... then, without the quotes, the rendered script would look like this:

```
var msg = Something
```

Which would be invalid, because there's no variable named "Something".