# How to fill javascript variables with c# ones?

Tags: c#, javascript, razor

I have these lines in my view.cshtml:

```
$("document").ready(function(){
    @{
        var cx = Json.Encode(ViewBag.x);
        var cy = Json.Encode(ViewBag.y);
    }
    var x = @cx;
    var y = @cy;
});
```

But now there is a red line under `;` in javascript codes and the error is `Syntax error`.

What is the problem?

Comment: Use `@` or `@()` directives to interpret razor correctly when is required.

Comment: Your solution will be found in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5614941/mix-razor-and-javascript-code and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599169/using-razor-within-javascript

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must enclose the js variables unless they are numeric or boolean

```
$("document").ready(function(){
    @{
        var cx = Json.Encode(ViewBag.x);
        var cy = Json.Encode(ViewBag.y);
    }
    var x = "@cx";
    var y = "@cy";
});
```

Comment: I don't get why one would want a string of JSON and not a JS object literal .. also it seems like it (the JSON) would be invalid in the final HTML output?

Comment: @user2864740 I just need a json too fill hicharts category and series.highcharts.com.

Answer (score 2):

Try to enclose the variables in `""` like this:

```
$("document").ready(function(){
    @{
        var cx = Json.Encode(ViewBag.x);
        var cy = Json.Encode(ViewBag.y);
    }
    var x = "@cx";
    var y = "@cy";
});
```

You may also want to check [ASP.NET MVC 3: Razor’s @: and  syntax](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/15/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax.aspx)

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something .. why would someone want a *string* for "JSON-encoded" data? Wouldn't they want a JS object literal? Also it seems like it would just be *invalid* JS ..