# How to call client side click on html submit button in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Hello Friends,
 please help me i am new  in MVC Dot net, and i am try to insert label value on database i have a two labels first for IP address and Second for Current running time and  three submit buttons checkin, checkout and going for personal task.
 on page load checkout and personal task buttons are hidden, only show 2 labels and check in button.
 when i am clicking on checkin button both labels value stored in database ms sql2008 . and automatically checkout and personal task button should be enabled and check in button should be disabled.
           when i am doing this task with jquery or java script on click event then my insertion task on controller not working only jquery worked.

please help me how i can calling client side click event with html submit button..

my code is:
  on view -->

```
 <button id="btnchkin" value="CheckIn" type="submit" name="action"/>
  <input type="submit"  id="btntask" name="action"  value="PersonalTask" />
   <input type="submit" id="btnchkout" name="action"  value="CheckOut" />
```

on script tag -->

```
 $("#btnchkin").click(function () {

    alert("a");
    //  $('#btnchkin').prop('disabled', true);
    $('#btntask').prop('disabled', false);
    $('#btnchkout').prop('disabled', false);
    $('#btnchkin').prop('disabled', true);

    //alert("b");
});
```

and controller-->

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("Index")]
public ActionResult Index( string lblIP1)
{

        DateTime datetime = DateTime.Now;
        string date = datetime.ToString();
        date = datetime.Date.ToString();
        lblIP1 = ipp;
        string ip = lblIP1;

        string s = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt");

        EmployeeSchedule emp = new EmployeeSchedule();
        emp.IP = ip;
        emp.CurrentDate = Convert.ToDateTime(date);
        emp.CheckInTime = s.ToString();

        BAL_EmployeeSchedule employeeBusinessLayers = new BAL_EmployeeSchedule();
        employeeBusinessLayers.AddEmployee(emp);

        ViewBag.ip = ipp;


    return View();
}
```

Comment: Hello, so do you want to push a button in your browser and return data from your server to the client via JSON or do you want the page to reload and return a model containing your data?

Comment: No i just want to enabled and disabled buttons

Comment: I don't know what that means.  What buttons do you want to enable and disable, and upon what conditions do you want them to be so?

Comment: in server tags <asp:input "button" />   we can use OnClientClick event to use jquery or java script . same i want this in mvc

Comment: When i clicked on First(checkin) button, other 2 buttons should be enable and first button (checkin) should be disabled.with inserting labels data on database. other 2 buttons ( checkout and personal task buttons) are disabled on page load .

Comment: Ok, let me post you a solution for that.  One moment...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your controller method:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    // return view to show three buttons...
    ViewBag.IsCheckedIn = false;
    return View();
}
```

Here is your view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        @if (ViewBag.IsCheckedIn)
        {
            <text>
                $('#btntask').prop('disabled', false);
                $('#btnchkout').prop('disabled', false);
                $('#btnchkin').prop('disabled', true);
            </text>
        }
        else
        {
            <text>
                $('#btntask').prop('disabled', true);
                $('#btnchkout').prop('disabled', true);
                $('#btnchkin').prop('disabled', false);
            </text>
        }
    });
</script>
<button id="btnchkin" value="CheckIn" type="submit" name="action"/>
<input type="submit"  id="btntask" name="action"  value="PersonalTask" />
<input type="submit" id="btnchkout" name="action"  value="CheckOut" />
```

Here is your post controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.IsCheckedIn = true;
    return View();
}
```

Please let me know if this is what you wanted.

Comment: yes @user1477388 i want same this but when i am doing this script tag then i want error on $('#btnchkin') "Too many characters in character literal"

Comment: Sorry, you must also add `<text>` for Razor + javascript.  See my edit.

Comment: You need the `@` if you want it to be executed as Razor, but you could remove it and then put `if (@ViewBag.IsCheckedIn)` and it would be executed as javascript.  Let me know how it works out.

Comment: I just learned two days about MVC and i must to do this task in 2 days for my job.. please help me out.. please  ..

Comment: Of course I will help you.  But, first I must know what the problem is.  If your code is like mine then it should work without issue as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5614941/mix-razor-and-javascript-code.  Have you tried building your project/solution?  Sometimes, the IDE will say there is a syntax error, when there actually is no error.

Comment: Thank You so much @user1477388  .now my data is storing in database and enabled disabled is also working nice.. using <text>  it works great . whats the mean of <text> here...why we used this...

Comment: can you solve my other problem . now on click of personal task button on text area will open like jquery and background  form will disable. and text area value will save in db.

Comment: Post a new question with a link back here.  If I can't help you, someone else likely will try.

Comment: ya i have already created new question for that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23007760/how-to-show-textarea-popup-window-on-submit-button-in-mvc-dotnet