# How to show textarea popup window on submit button in MVC DotNet

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

i am working on mvc dot net, and i have one button and when i clicked on this button i want to display one popup box with textarea and text of text area will insert on db.
this all working with MVC razor.

like this..my code on this URL

[How to call client side click on html submit button in mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22989631/how-to-call-client-side-click-on-html-submit-button-in-mvc/22990214?noredirect=1#comment35154558_22990214)

Comment: First show the code you have done so far.

Comment: i have only one submit button.. and click on submit button i want to show popup box that having one textarea and ok button. that's it..

Comment: You can use JQuery dialog and for your`OK` button an ajax call. better to show what you have done so there will be help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22989631/how-to-call-client-side-click-on-html-submit-button-in-mvc/22990214?noredirect=1#comment35154558_22990214       this is my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this code for jquery ui dialog box https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#default

You will have to create a dialog like so and submit your value via ajax:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#myButton').click(function(){
            $('#dialog').dialog('open');
        });

        $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            buttons: {
                "OK": function() {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '@Url.Action("myAjaxMethodAction", "myController")',
                        type: 'post',
                        data: $('#myForm').serialize(),
                        success: function() {
                            $('#dialog').dialog('close');
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
    <form id="myForm">
        <textarea id="myTextArea"></textarea>
    </form>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you could put your text area in a Razor form and just submit the page on submit which would post it to a regular MVC action like you would regularly.

Comment: not working for me.. :(  . only showing text box on my page . i want to show this popup on button click . and submit this txtarea data on db.

Comment: See my edit; when you click a link with the ID of `myButton` it will open the `dialog` which displays a text box.  When you click OK, it should serialize the data in `myForm` and send it to the URL specified as JSON.