# Can c#/Razor work with DyGraph WITHOUT Javascript?

Tags: c#, razor, dygraphs

In this question:
[Previous DyGraph question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24811899/passing-c-sharp-variable-using-mvc-razor-for-use-with-dygraph)

There is still the need to go to JavaScript to call DyGraph:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
g = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("readingGraph"), @data,{ labels: ["Sample Number", "Reading"] });
</script>
```

Is there anyway to remove JavaScript completely?

I would like a fully c# solution...

Comment: I mean, you could use C# to write JavaScript to the output stream... But at some point it starts getting a little silly. You're interacting with a JavaScript component; embrace the madness ;).

Answer (score 2):

Ah, OBVIOUSSLY not. DyGraph is a javascript library. If you want to remove Javascript completely, you need to use a graph library that generates the graph on the server and sends the picture down to the client. Given that DyGraph is a javascript library - the obvious answer is no, it can not be used while at the same time totally disabling javascript.

Literally on the homepage it says: "dygraphs is a fast, flexible open source JavaScript charting library.".

Comment: I see. I was hoping for a "Wrapper" to use within the c# body. Is there a Client-side c# based plotting package that would give easier functionality?

Comment: Ah, we do not recommend software and tools here.

Comment: You don't need to generate an image on the server. You can generate svg with Blazor, or generate an image and then put it into a canvas.

Answer (score 0):

If you want 100% C# and no Javascript, MudBlazor has some charting capabilities: https://mudblazor.com/components/barchart#api

As another answer states, "Given that DyGraph is a javascript library - the obvious answer is no, it can not be used while at the same time totally disabling javascript"