# using razor variables in javascript code(get value and change value using javascript)

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a variable in razor which has time value. I want to change it to the correct client's local time. I cannot use the variable in javascript code...

```
<script type="text/javascript">                             
    var tm =  @arraystr[9] ;
    var newDate = new Date(date.getTime() + date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000);
    var offset = date.getTimezoneOffset() / 60;
    var hours = date.getHours();
    newDate.setHours(hours - offset);
    @arraystr[9] = newDate;
</script>

<div class="mtime">@arraystr[9]</div>
```

THis is code in the partial View called by Index View...
An alternative way, is to use javascript code in Index View to change the time value in all div tags where class="mtime"...
the javascript code is called before body tag ends:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('mtime');
            [].slice.call(divs).forEach(function (div) {

                var date = div.InnerHTML;
                var newDate = new Date(date.getTime() + date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000);

                var offset = date.getTimezoneOffset() / 60;
                var hours = date.getHours();

                newDate.setHours(hours - offset);
                div.InnerHTML = newDate;

            });


        </script>

    </body>
```

nothing of these 2 works...

Comment: Please ask google first..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mix Razor and Javascript code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5614941/mix-razor-and-javascript-code)

Comment: I have viewed many similar questions and solutions, nothing worked...

Comment: I'm not sure if it is possible to achieve this if the javascript is located within external file. At least not without using a call to controller which would then return time.

Comment: Razor code is parsed on the server **before** its sent to the view. Javascript is client side code. Razor code cannot access a javascript variable that does not even exist yet!

Comment: the code above is in partial view called by index view. I could call the function for all the mtime class divs in index...

Comment: I have to assume you've got a `DateTime` in .net. In this case you have to wrap it in quotes, i.e. `var myDate = '@myVar';` and then parse it, i.e. with moment (if necessary) and eventually replace the content of the elements with `mtime` as class.

Comment: yess, I ll better ask a new question and explain things more clear..

Answer (score 0):

To set c# variable into javascript try syntax as below:

```
var jsVar = "@cSharpVar";
```

Comment: thanks, but I ll better ask a new question and give details in a more appropriate way

Comment: as Stephen said it will not work because i expect javascript code to be executed with razor at the same time

Comment: you are right, It's impossible, because javascript code run after page rendered on server, but in this way you can initialize your javascript variables