# Cannot access properties of model in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-5

I have tried a few suggestions on here however did not seem to work, I cannot seem to access the properties of the model.  This is what I have so far

```
var widgetModel = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.widgets))';
                [].forEach.call(widgetModel, function (widget) {
                    var template = document.querySelector('#panel-template');
                    var panelTitle = template.querySelector('.panel-title');
                    panelTitle.textContent = widget.WidgetName;
                });
```

Here is the rendered widgetmodel
http://gyazo.com/4a960969d9bedbd71efb1dac9b99c7e6

I have also tried to access it like this, however there doesn't seem to be any properties hanging off the widget variable.

```
for (var i = 0; i < widgetCount; i++) {
                        var widget = widget[i];
                        var template = document.querySelector('#panel-template');
                        var panelTitle = template.querySelector('.panel-title');
                        panelTitle.textContent = widget.WidgetName;
                    }
```

Comment: try to add the rendering of 'widgetModel' to your question

Comment: @Infer-On I have added the rendering of the widget model

Comment: @Johnathon64, perhaps I am misunderstanding and my answer did not help. What do you mean cannot access model properties? After trying my suggestion, did you try console.log(widgetModel) to make sure it has data?

Comment: Hi @AmmarCSE I can get the data, I know there is data being assigned to widgetModel, however I am unsure how to access the individual properties of that model e.g. WidgetID, WidgetName etc...

Comment: @Johnathon64, can you show me a console.log(widgetModel) ?

Comment: @AmmarCSE sorry it took so long to get back but here is the console output, http://gyazo.com/87a432a1527d2b99d33b45b76da11a8d

Answer (score 1):

Mixing javascript and Razor requires that you surround your Razor call with any code block

`@{ ... }` or `@if(condition){}`, etc.

and putting the code itself in an escaped sequence

`@:` or the `<text>` tag.

So, knowing this, you can do something like

```
@{
        <text>
            var widgetModel = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.widgets))';
        </text>
     }
```

See [Mix Razor and Javascript code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5614941/mix-razor-and-javascript-code) and [Using Razor within JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599169/using-razor-within-javascript)