# How can we put ViewBag data in $scope object?

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, angularjs-scope, viewbag

I am newbie in Angular and sending ViewBag data from ActionResult into the View. where in the view i want to access the ViewBag and put the content in the $scope object like

```
$scope.productList = ViewBag.productList;
```

but not having any idea about how to do this. Please suggest any reference.

Update:

I tried to get the ViewBag object in Window scope and then window scope to $scope object. but it does not work out.

```
        <script>
            window.Category = [];
            @foreach (var listItem in (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Categories)
            {
                window.Category.Add(listItem.Text);
            }


        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try using `<script type="text/javascript">`
that allowed you to mix razor and javascript

see [hare](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5614995/1509853) and [hare](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4599403/1509853)