# Pushing values to javascript array returning lots of errors

Tags: javascript, google-maps, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm tring to fill a javascript array with lat longs that I can use to put markers on a map from my model but it's riddled with errors and I'm not sure why.

```
<div id="map"></div>
<script>

    var map,
    points = [];

    @foreach (var a in Model) {
        //Error: The name 'points' does not exist in the current context
                   //Error: ) expected ; expected (at front and end brackets)
        points.push({ lat: @a.Lat, lng: @a.Lon });
    }

    function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 },
            zoom: 8
        });
        //Error: The name 'points' does not exist in the current context
        @foreach (var p in points) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: p });
            //Error: The name 'marker' does not exist in the current context
            //Error: The name 'map' does not exist in the current context
            marker.setMap(map);
        }
    }

</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MyKey&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
```

## Model

```
public class Vehicle
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public decimal Lon { get; set; }
    public decimal Lat { get; set; }
    public string VehType { get; set; }
    public string Driver { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `@foreach` is razor code. It is evaluated on the server before its sent to the view. `points` is a client side javascript variable which does not even exist at that point - its not in scope.

Comment: And I have just noticed this is a repeat of your [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33816493/using-javascript-arrays-filled-with-model-data-to-add-google-map-markers). Please delete one or the other

Comment: So what would the solution be?

Comment: You just need to assign you Model to a javascript array, for example `var points = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))`. The first `foreach` is not required and the second needs to replace with a javascript loop.

Comment: If your show your model (and delete the other question) I can add an answer.

Comment: I've added the model and deleted the previous question.

Comment: No problem, I've been pulling my hair out for hours over this, whats a few more minutes 8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@foreach()` is razor code. It is evaluated on the server before its sent to the view. `points` is a client side javascript variable which does not exist at that point - its not in scope. Instead, you can assign your model to a javascript array using `@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)`. Your script would then be

```
var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)); // ignore the annoying 'syntax error'
points = [];
$.each(model, function (index, item) {
    points.push({ lat: item.Lat, lng: item.Lon})
})
function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 },
        zoom: 8
    });
    for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: points[i] });
        marker.setMap(map);
    }
}
```

Comment: That fixes the top part, but what about the second for loop that places the markers?

Comment: That's some progress! I'm not seeing markers still but at least the map is working and I'm not getting any syntax errors.

Comment: Actually markers just showed up, thank you for all the help!

Comment: Quick question, do you know how I would set the initial coordinates to the first pair in the points array?

Comment: You can get the first set of coordinates using `var initial = points[0];` but I'm not sure what you mean by _"set the initial coordinates"_

Comment: in the `initMap()` function you set the initial center of the map. So I would like to set it to the first pair of lat lng coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because inside the `@foreach` loop, it's C# code, not Javascript. And your `points` is a Javascript variable, so you cannot just place it like that.

To fix this, you have 2 ways:

1. Wrap it within `<text>` tag:

`<text>points.push({ lat: @a.Lat, lng: @a.Lon });</text>`

2. In case your Javascript only has one line, you can use `@:` like this:

`@:points.push({ lat: @a.Lat, lng: @a.Lon });`

Comment: Again, this is server side code - `points` does not exist so the same error will occur.

Comment: Are you sure? I'm sure wrapping it inside `<text>` tag will solve your problem. Please take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5614941/mix-razor-and-javascript-code/5614995#5614995)

Comment: You correct, it will work despite the multiple error the RazorTemplateEngine reports, and if the values are numbers only (otherwise you have to determine what to quote and what not quote).

Comment: @StephenMuecke Razor has always had problems with JS output and many times it's just parser errors but the page will compile just fine.