# Jquery If condition not applying on function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am working on MVC application , i want to apply one if condition but not working. i am missing something. It says too many characters in character literal

> Invalid expression term {

```
    (function () {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            app.applyDatatable("tblInitPricing", false, [7], [7], 5, "desc", true);
            var sr = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.CanvasJsonData));
            @if(Model.IsValidCanvasUser)
            { //i am trying to open this curly braces here               
                Sfdc.canvas(function() {
                Sfdc.canvas.client.publish(sr.client, {
                    name: 'mybox.sendVal', payload: { value : 'request created'} });
                }) () ;
            }//i am trying to end this curly braces here     
        }); 
    })();
```

Comment: What does the resulting HTML actually look like? The issue will hopefully be clear from looking at that.

Comment: I guess it depends where the error occurs. If it occurs in the browser, then I'm asking what is the HTML output. (This is the code that runs on your server, and emits HTML that is then interpreted by the browser. What is that HTML?)

Comment: If the error instead occurs on the server, then perhaps you can share the exact error message and what line of code it says is the problem?

Comment: no it is compile time error..

Comment: Assign the values of the javascript objects before your function (i.e. `var isValid = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.IsValidCanvasUser)`

Comment: @user662285 Can you share the exact error message and which line it occurs on?

Comment: @StephenMuecke: Edited but same error. See my edited script above

Comment: No, You did not understand. The `var isValid = ...` is the first line of code, then replace the razor `@if()` with `if(isValid) { ..`

Comment: @Stephen : Thanks it works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While its possible to swap between razor (server side code) and javascript (client side code) using `<text>` or `@:`, for example (refer also [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5614941/mix-razor-and-javascript-code) for more detail)

```
app.applyDatatable("tblInitPricing", false, [7], [7], 5, "desc", true);
var sr = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.CanvasJsonData));
@if(Model.IsValidCanvasUser)
{
    <text>           
        Sfdc.canvas(function() {
        Sfdc.canvas.client.publish(sr.client, {
            name: 'mybox.sendVal', payload: { value : 'request created'} });
        })() ;
    </text>
}
// Razor may report syntax errors, but you can ignore them
```

it is easier to just assign the value of `IsValidCanvasUser` to a javascript variable and use that in a javascript `if` block

```
var isValid = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.IsValidCanvasUser));
var sr = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.CanvasJsonData));
if(isValid) {
    Sfdc.canvas(function() {
    ....
}
```