# How can I write razor inside javascript code?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, razor

I want to write a razor code

```
@Html.DropDownList("","Select One")
```

inside javascript function

```
$function()
```

in a partial view.

Comment: You can't, Razor is running on the server side, and javascript on the client side. What are you exactly trying to do?  If you're trying to select an element of a dropdown list, you could do it by simple javascript code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mix Razor and Javascript code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5614941/mix-razor-and-javascript-code)