# Function inside C# for loop inside Razor Page to hide/unhide photos

Tags: javascript, c#, razor

I'm tryin to set a function inside a for loop within a c# cshtml file. The purpose of this function is to unhide photos on button click so users can see them.

```
            @if (Model.Photos.PhotosBase64 != null)
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < Model.Photos.PhotosBase64.Count; i++)
                {
                    <h1 class="font-weight-bold">Photo @(i + 1)</h1>
                    <input type="button" value="Show Button" onclick="showImage();"/>
                    <img alt="" id="loadingImage_@i" src="data:image/png;base64, @Model.Photos.PhotosBase64.ElementAt(i)" style="visibility:hidden"/>  

                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => Model.Photos.PhotosBase64[i])
                    <input type="submit" value="Remove Photo" class="btn btn-danger" id="removephoto-btn" asp-action="RemovePhoto" asp-route-index="@i" />
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                              <%= function showImage(){document.getElementById('loadingImage_'+i).style.visibility="visible";}> </%>

                }
            }
```

I've read that <%=> can open up a javascript section but it doesn't seem to be working correctly probably because of my missing syntax or using it in the wrong context. I've tried several different formats but left the most recent attempt on the page for some visualization. How can I use JS to hide/unhide photos by selecting their ID? (or other method if more effective)

Comment: I think you're combining the syntax of WebForms and Razor.

Comment: *"I've read that <%=> can open up a javascript section"* - Where did you read that?  I would expect a `<script>` element for JavaScript code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mix Razor and Javascript code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5614941/mix-razor-and-javascript-code)

Comment: The photos are contained in a particular location. Will that text/Javascript tag essentially replace a div or be contained within a div to allow for specific page placement? If yes, then that is exactly the answer.

Comment: @David I don't see where I found that suggestion anymore. I'm probably losing it haha. Normally I always use a script but I couldn't place a plain <script by itself> My div tag also didn't approve of a script inside of it. I wouldn't expect that to be where it goes as I normally have my main <script> at the bottom with reference scripts like jquery cnds in the head. I was just trying to see if I could do things this way and iterate with the model count.

Comment: @HankMorgan: Honestly it sounds like you might need to take a step back and look at a bigger picture of the overall page.  For starters, even if you replace this with a `<script>` element, you're outputting that element in a loop and will be re-defining a function called `showImage` over and over.  So only the last one will be used.

Comment: @HankMorgan: Perhaps you could define a single `showImage` function in JavaScript for the page, and that function would accept as a parameter the `id` of the element it targets.  Then within this loop your calls to that function would include that `id` value.

Comment: Yes, thank you. That worked when I tried it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, JavaScript code goes in a `<script>` element.

Aside from that, the logic of what you're doing is a bit odd.  Consider that you are outputting this code *in a loop*.  Which means the page is going to have many different versions of a function called `showImage`, each one over-writing the previous.  So only the last one will actually be called.

Define *one* function (probably at the bottom of the page, certainly not in a loop) which performs the operation you want, and have it require whatever information it needs to perform that operation.  In this case that information is the `id` of the target element:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function showImage(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.visibility="visible";
  }
</script>
```

Then within the loop you can invoke that function, supplying the `id` values accordingly:

```
<input type="button" value="Show Button" onclick="showImage('loadingImage_@i');"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This the answert

```
    @if (Model.Photos.PhotosBase64 != null)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < Model.Photos.PhotosBase64.Count; i++)
            {
                <h1 class="font-weight-bold">Photo @(i + 1)</h1>
                <input type="button" value="Show Button" 
onclick="showImage('loadingImage_@i');"/>
                <img alt="" id="loadingImage_@i" src="data:image/png;base64, 
@Model.Photos.PhotosBase64.ElementAt(i)" style="visibility:hidden"/>  

                <br/>
                <br/>
                @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => Model.Photos.PhotosBase64[i])
                <input type="submit" value="Remove Photo" class="btn btn-danger" id="removephoto-btn" asp-action="RemovePhoto" asp-route-index="@i" />
                <br/>
                <br/>
                          

            }
        }
<script type="text/javascript">
  function showImage(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.visibility="visible";
  }
</script>
```

You have to have a javascript method to make photos visible. and yo must pass yor desired image id to that function